# express is unable to authenticate

Tags: node.js, authentication

I have been following mean stack videos done by microsoft visual academy(mva). I have been struck at module 3 of MVA. When I enter a username and password, it always redirects to failure route.

passport.js:

```
passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) {

        if (users[username]){
            console.log('User already exists with username: ' + username);
            return done(null, false);
        }

        //store user in memory 
        users[username] = {
            username: username,
            password: createHash(password)
        }

        console.log(users[username].username + ' Registration successful');
        return done(null, users[username]);
    })
);
```

authenticate.js:

```
 router.get('/success', function(req, res){
    res.send({state: 'success', user: req.user ? req.user : null});
});

//sends failure login state back to angular
router.get('/failure', function(req, res){
    res.send({state: 'failure', user: null, message: "Invalid username or password"});
});

//log in
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect: '/auth/success',
    failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
}));
```

[image]

I actually followed steps given in https://github.com/hwz/chirp/tree/master/module-3

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you handle this problem somehow? Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try changing Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've got solution for you. Don't send data in headers but via payload. Yes, it's simple as it.

By the way I recommend you to check in `passport.js` login method. There is typo in their Github respository. They've forget `!` symbol in

`if(users[username]){
   console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
   return done(null, false);
}`

so it should be:

`if(!users[username]){
   console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
   return done(null, false);
}`